# How to get all file and folders of a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I have a server that a docker container is running on. I can see it by running `docker container ls`:

[image]

And finding the image by running `docker image ls`:

[image]

I also can open the container using this command `docker exec -it <container_hash> sh`. All I need to do is making a zip file from the files of the project. I mean these files:

[image]

So, how can I copy/paste all files of a running container and make a zip file of them on the server? Noted that I use Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

`docker cp` is your friend here:

```
Usage:  docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH

Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem

Use '-' as the source to read a tar archive from stdin
and extract it to a directory destination in a container.
Use '-' as the destination to stream a tar archive of a
container source to stdout.

Options:
  -a, --archive       Archive mode (copy all uid/gid information)
  -L, --follow-link   Always follow symbol link in SRC_PATH
```

So in your case you could use

```
docker cp <container_name>:/app /local/path/for/directory
```

This will copy the directory out to your local file system.  From there you can use a utility to create an archive in whatever format you want.

Comment: The docker cp documentation is here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/. If you omit the dest path you can pipe the output directly to tar to create your zip file in one line too.